# Where to place sql queries in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have started a rails project on top of a legacy database. Standard practices required to use an ORM, like assigning ID field to each table, haven't been followed. So, I will not be creating all the models matching all the table. I need to run queries joining multiple tables  using numerous conditions. I will mostly be using Model.find_by_sql or Model.connection.select_all methods. Where should I put these queries? Should I stash these in one of the models I have created that is involved in the query?
What's the standard practice for such a situation?

Comment: The standard practice is to use the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

As much as possible, you still want to insulate the rest of your application from the details of the database by putting your queries and whatnot into the model layer. So yes, "stashing" in the right model object relevant to what you're trying to do seems like the right thing.

Are you allowed to change the schema of the database? If so, you may want to use migrations to slowly make your database look more like a standard ActiveRecord backing store.

You may also want to look into alternatives to ActiveRecord such as [Sequel](http://sequel.heroku.com).

Answer (score -1):

It is good idea to place the sql queries under sql folder under db. You need to create the sql folder.